# TFF : Is the increase in the size of the dataset proportional to the increase in number of rounds?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

Let's suppose that we started our training with an image dataset of 500 images. So, I would like to know each time we increase the database, we have to increase the number of rounds to achieve good performance?

Thanks for giving me your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you won't get a general answer, which would likely need to depend on other properties of the problem you have. Some example thoughts...

If the learning problem is very easy and 500 images is enough, you likely don't need to change anything and have the same result.

If the learning problem is very hard, 500 images need not be enough to get good performance, no matter what you do with it.

If the learning problem is neither easy nor hard, at some point the answer will depend on how complexity of optimization the relates to the difficulty of the learning problem. Some ideas could be found for instance in [The Tradeoffs of Large Scale Learning](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2007/file/0d3180d672e08b4c5312dcdafdf6ef36-Paper.pdf) but I am not aware of similar research specific for the setup relevant for federated learning.